# Can not stop mysqld after database upgrade

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, percona, galera, percona-xtradb-cluster

I have an old Galera cluster (MySQL 5.5) that I am upgrading to Percona XtraDB (MySQL 5.7) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have successfully imported the database with xtrabackup and synced the cluster - so far so good.

My problem is that I can not stop the mysqld process on the first node, the one I started with `service mysql bootstrap-pxc` with the normal `service mysql stop`; I have to resort to `mysqladmin shutdown`. The odd thing is that once I have restarted the first node with `service mysql start` I can then sometimes stop it with `service mysql stop` without problems and sometimes not. I have yet to find a pattern to this.

All other nodes in the cluster can be shut down with `service mysql stop` without problems.

Answer (score 0):

When starting a Percona XtraDB cluster in bootstrap mode, the way to close it is to issue the command `service mysql bootstrap-stop`. The first node was started correctly with the bootstrap command and it is important to stop it the same way (and then start it anew, this time with the normal command `service mysql start` in order to make the first node a normal cluster member)